# How do you initialize a FormCollection with properties in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, initialization, formcollection

I've tried the usual way of:

```
var form = new FormCollection { "WeekList" = weekfilter, "PracticeList" = practicefilter}
```

and all possible deviations I could think of, but ultimately had to seperate it apart as:

```
var form = new FormCollection();
form["WeekList"] = weekfilter;
form["PracticeList"] = practicefilter;
```

How can I initialize this inline? Is it possible? (I'm basically trying to mimic a form being submitted)

Comment: ideally you should be using model binding

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC (not core), you can initialize [`System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.formcollection?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) like this:

```cs
var form = new FormCollection {
    {"WeekList", weekfilter},
    {"PracticeList", practicefitler}
}
```

#### [Demo in .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0USedx)

But I'm not the right computer to test this. I'm basing this on the `.Add` method of FormCollection begin declared as:

```cs
public virtual void Add(
    string name,
    string value
)
```

What types are the filter variables declared as?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formcollection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in aspnet core, you can initialize like this:

```cs
var formCol = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>
{
    { "Field1", "String Value 1" },
    { "Field2", "String Value 2" },
    { "Field3", "String Value 3" }
});
```

#### [Demo in .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UQN3IM)

Then, if you need to create a controller with test data, you can pass to the controller create method like this:

```cs
// Call create controller with test data
_controller.Create(formCol);
```